Cloth edge springs with Subdivision
I'm creating a model where I want to Sew some islands together with the Cloth modifier. I use a Subdivion Modifier to keep my model non-destructive and easy adjustable with a lower poly count. However the Sewing edgesare not created by a Subdivision modifier. The only way I can think off now is to apply the Subdivision Modifier and add manually Sewing Edges.
Is there perhaps a better workflow to work with a low poly model and Sewing Edges?

AFAIK the cloth modifier uses faceless edges between islands of faces as the sewing edges. You should already have them ready to go, from what you're showing here. Do you have Sewing checked in the Cloth modifier? It's under the Shape tab in the modifier.

@Jakemoyo Maybe I didn't explained it clear: I use a Subdivision Modifier to create more faces - but it's not making the extra needed faceless edges between the two islands. I still have to manually apply the subd and add edges by hand.

Okay, it's a bit awkward but I think you can get this fixed pretty procedurally, or at least without too much fiddling.
Here's the starting mesh.

Before subdividing, select one of the sewing edges and use the Select Similar menu with Shift+G. Add that selection to a vertex group.
This will make selection easier after applying the SubSurf mod.

Apply one level of subdivision.

Select one of the verts in the center of the sewing edges and press Shift+G to Select Similar, with Amount of Adjacent Faces  as the option.

Ctrl+X to dissolve those.

Then click Select under the vertex group panel to select those verts. It'll be slightly too big in all directions, just press Ctrl+NumpadMinus to shrink it down.


Then press F to fill those faces.

Then you do these two operations, Triangulate faces, followed by Tris to Quads, in succession to convert these into the quads we want. On alot of meshes it won't work quite as cleanly, but since this is a just-subdivided mesh it figures it out exactly.

Then just X > Delete > Only Faces.

Finished mesh:

Like i said, it's not 100% procedural, but it should be something you can do without having to manually fill each face by hand. Just a half dozen operations.

I've +1 it for the effort creating a good workflow option, but I'll won't accept it as solving answer in case of future answers that will be more procedural or non-destructive. Thanks!
